# Непредвиденное появление: "%%a"

Tags: cmd

```
for %%a in (*.webm) DO ffmpeg -i "%%a"  -c:v copy -c:a opus -strict -2 "output\%%.webm"
```

Непредвиденное появление: "%%a".

Почему такая ошибка, если по идее сразу после `for` `%%a` — это объявление переменной?

Answer (score 4):

Двойной процент надо писать только в bat-файле. А если ты набираешь эту команду порсто в консоли, то надо использовать один знак процента.